# Exporting shapefile from ArcGIS Desktop into Autodesk Ecotect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, 3d, autocad

I am trying to export a shapefile from ArcGIS 10 into Autodesk Ecotect Analysis 2011 for solar analysis. I have a shapefile with polygons, and the heights of buildings is stored in the attribute table. I tried saving it as a KML file but Ecotect does not import KML files. Instead, Ecotect would accept any DXF or 3D files (such as 3D Metafile and 3D Studio).

Is there a way of saving 3D files from GIS other than KML?

I tried importing KML into Sketchup and Autocad without success.

Any other idea for exporting shapefiles into a software that can extrude them and save as 3D would help too!

Comment: How do you convert the shapefiles from ArcGIS to Ecotect? I am trying to do that for solar analysis. Could you explain your solution for me?

Comment: Hello how did you export extruded 3d features from ArcScene to Ecotect. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can export a 3D model from ArcScene using the 'Export Scene' tool with file format VRML (*.wrl), which can be then imported into Ecotect for further analysis. Import a VRML file into Ecotect as a 3D CAD geometry (by going to: File/Import/3D CAD Geometry). It is important to consider the scale of the objects in the drawing, which can be adjusted in this step. In my case, the scale was changed from metres to millimetres by scaling the features by 1,000. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS 10...
right click on the shapefile in the TOC (table of contents),
Choose Data>
Export to CAD.

If you have map3d it will import 3d shapefiles and then you have extensive 3d capability in autocad (same as map3d).

Comment: Thanks! But I dont have map3d. I could extrude the polygons manually in autocad but I work with big portions of cities and want an automated way to extrude them from the attribute table.. any ideas?

Comment: the first part was instruction for arcgis 10. did that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Brad! I finally found a solution by using ARCscene to save the 3D that can be imported into Ecotect.